# Auto update status

Tags: excel

I have a running list in tab2.

I'm wanting anything that falls under **issue "Missing Rope"** and **status "Pending"** to update the status of the correlating **cables effected "6RIV-20-20-FSL-641"**in tab1.

[Tab2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V3q2.png)
[Tab1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqAK7.png)

I'm really struggling on where to start.

Comment: Use `IF()` function.

Comment: I'm not very experienced with excel and would need assistance in the formula.